# Prove that if $f$ is injective, then $f(x)\in f(A_0)\implies x\in A_0$.

Tags: functions

This is part of a bigger proof I'm doing. I would like to see the following statement proved from the definition of "injective".

Prove that if $f$ is injective, $f(x)\in f(A_0)\implies x\in A_0$.

Answer (score 2):

What does it mean for a function to be injective? This means that $f(x)=f(y)\implies x=y$. What is $f(A)$? This is the image of $A$ under $f$, so $f(A)=\{f(y):y\in A\}$. Hence, $$f(x)\in f(A)\implies f(x)=f(y)~\text{for some $y\in A$}\implies...$$

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)\in f(A_0)$, then $f(x)=f(a_0)$ for some $a_0\in A_0$. By injectivity, $x=a_0$. Hence $x\in A_0$.